# How to count standard deviation of a vector in R without an element?

Tags: r, for-loop, standard-deviation

I would like to calculate the standard deviation of a vector except the ith element in R and do this with every element. So for example I have a vector a(1 2 3) and count the sd of (1 2 ) (1 3) and (2 3 ) too. Thx for help!

Comment: see `jackknife` in `bootstrap`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `combn` function it has a `FUN` argument.

```
v <- 1:3
combn(v, length(v) - 1L, sd)
## [1] 0.7071068 1.4142136 0.7071068
```

Comment: Thank you! It is easier than I thought. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
v <- 1:3
sapply(1:length(v), function(i) sd(v[-i]))
```